# How to get column value from Ado.Net reader

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, ado.net

I am trying to get value of a given table column from Ado.Net as follows

```
 var query = "select transmission_time, actual_transaction_amount as sum_amount FROM table_name";

        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("connectionString"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);

            using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var amount = reader.GetDecimal(Convert.ToInt32(reader["sum_amount"]));
                    result.Add(amount.ToString());//= amount;
                }
            }
```

But I get an error

> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
> Blockquote

But when I change the line to this

```
var amount = reader.GetDecimal(Convert.ToInt64(reader["sum_amount"]));
```

I get the following error

> Argument 1 cannot convert from 'long' to 'int'

Please I need to convert the figures in that column to numbers and return it in my result.

The values in the column I am trying to get are like these examples

> 10000, 5000, 20000, etc. in a postgreSql table

The application is a Asp.Net 6 application running on Windows
Any help will be appreciated.
Thak you

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't make sense:

```cs
var amount = reader.GetDecimal(Convert.ToInt32(reader["sum_amount"]));
```

I assume that what you're actually trying to do there is get an `int` value from the `sum_amount` column and convert it to a `decimal`. What that code actually does is get a boxed `int` (i.e. an `object` reference) from the `sum_amount` column, unbox it and then use that `int` value as an index to get a `decimal` from a different column that probably doesn't exist. I think that what you actually meant to do was this:

```cs
var amount = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetInt64("sum_amount"));
```

Comment: It gave me this error
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Comment: @Josh, you probably need to call `GetInt64`. I have updated my answer. That said, you should probably use the debugger to see what the value of `reader["sum_amount"]` is when the exception is thrown.